# Working script to start Chromium not working via cron

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian, chromium

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 setup as a kiosk browser. I launch chromium on startup, and now I want to relaunch it a few times a day because chromium sometimes crashes.

I run Raspbian Jessie 8.0

I've made an executable script in `etc/cron.hourly/`. For testing purposes I currently trigger it every minute using crontab in `/var/spool/cron`. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill chromium
export DISPLAY=:0.0
chromium-browser http://www.google.com
```

If I run this script manually, it works fine. Chromium get killed and the new window opens. (Even from SSH, this works) But when it's triggered by crontab chromium closes, but it doesn't open a new window.

I don't know what to search for, is it a problem of chromium? cron? the script? If have no clue...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the script does not have a display when run from cron, so chromium's interface does not show.

Add

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

to your script before starting chromium and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

chrome uses some environment variables
you can store environment variables from /home/user1/.bashrc file

```
typeset -gx > /tmp/user1envvars
```

and /etc/crontab entry would look like

```
* * * * *   user1 /bin/bash -c 'source /tmp/user1envvars ; /snap/bin/chromium  args..'
```